# Strange behavior with TikZ animation

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, animate

I was trying to create an animated [TaiChi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiji_(philosophy)) symbol with TikZ and the `animate` package, and I encountered the following problem:

**If I don't add a bigger bounding box to the `tikzpicture`, then some frames in the resulting animation will "shrink".**

The following MWE illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\centering

This is wrong.\\
\newcommand\TaiChiWrong[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \fill[white](#1+180:1)arc(#1+180:#1:1)--cycle;  % black half-circle
    \fill(#1:1)arc(#1:#1-180:1)--cycle;             % white half-circle
    \fill(#1+180:.5)circle[radius=.5];              % black head
    \fill[white](#1:.5)circle[radius=.5];           % white head
    \fill(#1:.5)circle[radius=.1];                  % black eye
    \fill[white](#1+180:.5)circle[radius=.1];       % white eye
    \draw[gray](0,0)circle[radius=1cm];             % border
    \draw[red](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
    % \draw[blue](-1.3,-1.3)rectangle(1.3,1.3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{animateinline}[loop]{10}
  \multiframe{36}{i=90+-10}{\TaiChiWrong{\i}}
\end{animateinline}

\bigskip

This is correct.\\
\newcommand\TaiChi[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \fill[white](#1+180:1)arc(#1+180:#1:1)--cycle;  % black half-circle
    \fill(#1:1)arc(#1:#1-180:1)--cycle;             % white half-circle
    \fill(#1+180:.5)circle[radius=.5];              % black head
    \fill[white](#1:.5)circle[radius=.5];           % white head
    \fill(#1:.5)circle[radius=.1];                  % black eye
    \fill[white](#1+180:.5)circle[radius=.1];       % white eye
    \draw[gray](0,0)circle[radius=1cm];             % border
    \draw[red](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
    \draw[blue](-1.3,-1.3)rectangle(1.3,1.3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{animateinline}[loop]{10}
  \multiframe{36}{i=90+-10}{\TaiChi{\i}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

The only difference between the *wrong* and *correct* versions is that in the latter, a bigger bounding box (the blue one) is drawn. Moreover, the bigger bounding box has to somehow be "big enough": for example, if the blue box is `\draw[blue](-1.1,-1.1)rectangle(1.1,1.1);` the problem still exists.

I suspect that this problem is not related to `animate` because the problem still exists when I use `\foreach` to create a series of images.

My question is: **Why does a bigger bounding box make a difference?**

Comment: Recently, there was a similar discussion on the subject:http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140273.

Comment: Take a look at [my example with the `arc`s and `circle`s](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137264/16595). The red crosses represent the control points of the Bézier curves and are included in the bounding box.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thank you! Your explanation there is very helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TikZ automatically creates a bounding box to fit the contents.  To override, you can specify

```
\draw[use as bounding box](-1.3,-1.3)rectangle(1.3,1.3);
```

This is probably necessary due to the automatically-created bounding rectangle of your sequence of frames varying due to the varying placement of the elements in the picture.

You might also want to clip to this rectangle.

Edit in response to comments below:
In the current instance, the problem is that the TikZ bounding box of an arc is not actually the true bounding box of the arc.  Compare

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=5cm];
    \draw[color=blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) arc[start angle=20,end angle=200,radius=5cm];
    \draw[color=blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The reason for this (at a guess) is that the calculated bounding box includes the Bezier control points for the arc, which actually lie off the path.

I am not 100% familiar with the animate package, but it looks like it takes the bounding box of the first image as the "canvas" and then scales all subsequent images to fit.  Since the automatic bounding box of the images is wrong (as above) this creates the observed behaviour.

So following my earlier suggestion, something like this does work (I've checked)

```
\newcommand\TaiChiFixed[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \path[clip,use as bounding box](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
    \fill[white](#1+180:1)arc(#1+180:#1:1)--cycle;  % black half-circle
    \fill(#1:1)arc(#1:#1-180:1)--cycle;             % white half-circle
    \fill(#1+180:.5)circle[radius=.5];              % black head
    \fill[white](#1:.5)circle[radius=.5];           % white head
    \fill(#1:.5)circle[radius=.1];                  % black eye
    \fill[white](#1+180:.5)circle[radius=.1];       % white eye
    \draw[gray](0,0)circle[radius=1cm];             % border
    \draw[red](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question: Why does a bigger bounding box solve the problem of some frames in the animation being smaller than others?

Comment: OK I thought you just wanted a fix rather than a complete explanation.  I'll update the answer to explain more completely.

Comment: After all my edits, I have found that my guesses on the cause and correct solution are correct -- See page 8 of animate package documentation: http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf

Comment: Thanks! "the calculated bounding box includes the Bezier control points for the arc, which actually lie off the path" is exactly what I'm looking for `:)`

Comment: Someone needs to do this: http://floris.briolas.nl/floris/2009/10/bounding-box-of-cubic-bezier/